# I need to create a function that counts the number of different grades entered at the moment it just shows the most common grade

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```
//input variables

var students = [];
var marks = [];

//output variables

var grade = [];
var topMark = 0;
var topStudent = "";
var botMark = 0;
var award = "";
var error = "";
var Acount = 0;
var Bcount = 0;
var Ccount = 0;
var Fcount = 0;


//Getting Name and Mark

var index = 0;
var i = 0;
var name = prompt("Enter student name","Harry");

while (name != ""){
    students[index] = name;
    index++;
    var mark = prompt("Enter Mark " + name)
    marks[i] = mark;
    i++;
    name = prompt("Enter student name", "John");
};

//Getting Grade

function getGrade(mark){

    if (mark < 50){
    grade = "F";
    } else if (mark < 70){
    grade = "C";
    } else if (mark < 83){
    grade = "B";
    } else {
    grade = "A";
    } return grade;

}

// Top Student Function

function topStudent(){

}

// Top Mark Function

function topMark(){

}

// Bottom Mark Function

function botMark(){

}

// A, B, C, and F Count Function

function getCountOf(grades, grade){
    var count = 0;  
    for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i += 1){
        var count = grades[i];
        if (grades[i] == grade) {
            count += 1;
            }
    }
    return count;
}

//Display Table

document.write("<table>")
document.write("<tr><th>Student</th><th>Mark</th><th>Grade</th></tr>");
for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++){
    document.write("<tr><td>" + students[i] + "</td><td>" + marks[i] + "</td><td>" + getGrade(marks[i]) + "</td></tr>");
}
document.write("</table>");

// Display Bottom

if (students.length > 0){
    document.write("<br />");
    document.write("<br />");
    document.write("Top Student: " + topStudent);
    document.write("<br />");
    document.write("Top Mark: " + topMark);
    document.write("<br />");
    document.write("Bottom Mark: " + botMark);
    document.write("<br />");
    document.write("Number of A Marks: " + getCountOf(grade));
    document.write("<br />");
    document.write("Number of B Marks: " + getCountOf(grade));
    document.write("<br />");
    document.write("Number of C Marks: " + getCountOf(grade));
    document.write("<br />");
    document.write("Number of F Marks: " + getCountOf(grade));
}
```

I need help with the A, B, C, and F Count Function and how I am displaying it any help is welcome the display bottom is where I try and display the count of each grade A, B, C, and F but it only displays the mark most entered so if there are 3 A's 2 B's and a C it will display A next to all the counts.

Comment: is this a homework of somekind ?

Comment: `grade` is defined as an array at the top. Perhaps you got confused between `grades` and `grade`, variable names you've been using at multiple places with different meaning.

Comment: This is off-topic because there is no real question; you are simply soliciting help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dan Kuida mentioned, I hope this isn't homework of some kind, but I've changed your code below. I would've given you a JSFiddle to work with, but those sites don't agree with `document.write()` functions. Here are the two sections you need to change.

```
// A, B, C, and F Count Function

function getCountOf(grade) {
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < marks.length; i++) { // Could also use marks.forEach() here
    if (getGrade(marks[i]) === grade) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

You already have the marks saved and a function to convert them! No need for a grades array. Also note the `++` operator instead of the `+=`

```
// Display Bottom

if (students.length > 0) {
  document.write("<br />");
  document.write("<br />");
  document.write("Top Student: " + topStudent);
  document.write("<br />");
  document.write("Top Mark: " + topMark);
  document.write("<br />");
  document.write("Bottom Mark: " + botMark);
  document.write("<br />");
  document.write("Number of A Marks: " + getCountOf("A"));
  document.write("<br />");
  document.write("Number of B Marks: " + getCountOf("B"));
  document.write("<br />");
  document.write("Number of C Marks: " + getCountOf("C"));
  document.write("<br />");
  document.write("Number of F Marks: " + getCountOf("F"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is a big help was stuck on this problem for so long tried so many different ways and new I was close thanks for the answer!